# Generating one location while the phone is not moving

Tags: java, android

I would like to know **how can I generate one location using the gps or network providers while the phone is not moving more then something like 10 meters** which means you at home, or in the same place.

The minTime parameter doesn't really matters I guess (speaking about the requestLocationUpdates method of course), the minDistance is the one that should make the diffrence.
I tried to set the value to 100m but I keep getting locations while my didn't moved(maybe 1 meter.. was tested while I were sleeping) so I kept raising the value and I stoped in 500 meters!! since it became useless.

Maybe there is a way to check the distance between 2 locations?or receiving information about the phone movement?

Comment: What is your exact question? Can you concretize this? Anyway, have you had a look at the developer guide http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html ?

Comment: I bolded it, and I have read this page few times already and I still can't answer my question.

Comment: What exactly means "generate one location"? Do you want to pin down your location with more and more precision? Or do you simply want to have some fix?

Comment: I would like to generate a location and if the phone is moving more then 50 meters to generate another one. in that way I could move with my phone at home and only 1 location will be generated. The minDistance parameter doesn't solve this problem as mentioned.

Comment: The document I cited gives some advises how to handle this problem. You should add some logic that only accepts a new position if the accuracy is higher than the previous one. If you are not moving, the GPS hardware should detect this. It's normally not a good idea to implement your own logic for this.

Comment: Accepting a new position if the accuracy is higher than the previous one if I'm not moving sounds perfect to me, but how can I know that I'm not moving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind that GPS precision is on the order of +/- 20 meters. That, plus possible fluctuations in the available satellite signals due to environmental conditions, means that there is going to be some amount of change in the reported position, even for a stationary device.

The only reason `minDistance` would not be working for you is if it is feeding you positions where the *reported positions* are less than the minimum distance you requested. `LocationManager` can only work with the reported positions; it has no other way to determine whether or not the device is actually moving.

If you examine the data you get in your `LocationListener`, and you can demonstrate that the device is ignoring the `minDistance` parameter, report the bug to your device manufacturer. If, on the other hand, the issue is that you are getting fixes because the GPS subsystem thinks the device is moving (and therefore the positions differ by more than `minDistance`), that's a limitation of GPS and your hardware, and there is nothing you can do about that.

Comment: One could try to use other sensors to detect movement, but this seems to be a rather dirty workaround.

Comment: I don't think that the first case is relevant since I tested my application on 2 advanced devices, The Galaxy s3 and Note 2. So what you are saying is that it's impossible to generate 1 location while the phone is not moving more the X meters(It doesn't has to be that accurate .. I even used 500m as the minDistance parameter).

Comment: @ImriPersiado: "I don't think that the first case is relevant since I tested my application on 2 advanced devices, The Galaxy s3 and Note 2." -- "advanced devices" have nothing to do with firmware bugs.

Comment: @ImriPersiado: "So what you are saying is that it's impossible to generate 1 location while the phone is not moving more the X meters" -- no, I am saying that you need to look at the actual data to determine what is the source of your difficulty.

Comment: Ok, so how can I examine if the device is ignoring the minDistance parameter?

Comment: @ImriPersiado: You **look at the data**. If the distance between fixes is under `minDistance`, then `minDistance` is being ignored. There is a `distanceTo()` method on `Location` that can conveniently tell you the distance in meters between two `Location` objects.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I got my answer.